# Registering location based events in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

I'm working on an app where region monitoring is crucial and I want it to work in foreground and background (and when the app is terminated).

Is it better for my app to have delegate methods for location based events in the AppDelegate or in a ViewController where I setup all other data needed for my app to work? I'm asking this because somewhere I saw that in order for my app to register location based events in background (and when terminated) I have to setup delegate methods in the AppDelegate.

Can someone explain this to me and what would be the best way to organize this? Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you need to set AppDelegate as a delegate for `CLLocationManager` so you need not write all location related code in `AppDelegate`. I personally prefer having a class called LocationManager which deals with the location related stuff like permission handling, starting and stopping monitoring location changes etc etc. You can have a static shared instance of this manager or create a instance wherever is needed depending on your use case. In essence, CLLocationManager triggers methods on its delegates and that can be your custom object or AppDelegate whichever u choose

Comment: Okay, thank you :)